# How can we return the name of the button on which the user clicks in a webBrowser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I thought we should raise an event 
    This is what I have found:

```
event OnButtonClicked ()EventArgs;
HTMLButtonClickEventArgs:EventArgs
{
String ButtonName;
}
```

I am doing a web Browser control and this is the code I wrote for its button clicked,but I want to know on which button user clicks:

```
    public delegate void ButtonPressedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ButtonPressedEventHandler ButtonPressed;

    void OnButtonPressed()
    {
        if (ButtonPressed != null)
            ButtonPressed(this, new EventArgs());            
    }
```

Comment: Dose button located in webbrowser?

Comment: why not use `this.id`?

Comment: @irsog:No it is in html file

Comment: @Furqan:you mean whith if this.id=="ButtonID"?

Comment: your question is not clear,do you want to know with button clicked on form by user?

Comment: @irsog:Sorry,I have 3 buttons in an HTML file,which are shown in the webBrowser.
When the program is running,I want to know on which button the user clicks(like submit button or reset button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write an example for you:try this:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><button id=\"btn1\" type=\"button\">Click Me!</button><button id=\"btn2\" type=\"button\">Click Me!</button></body></html>";
        }
```

**Call Click event:**

```
     //Edited 
     bool First_Call = true;
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (First_Call)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click);
            First_Call = false;
        }
    }
```

**Get Active Element When User click on document but**

```
        void Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
           // **Edited**
           //Check Element is Button 
           if (webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.TagName == "BUTTON")
           {
            MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.Id);
           }
        }
```

Comment: @Pedram:also check active element is button or not.see my edit

Comment: @Pedram:and also notice `webBrowser1.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click);` must call for first page navigation completed,and dot call for sec time.if you call it again this event rised two time